# Socket IO + React Native + Rabbit MQ Architecture mix?

Tags: react-native, sockets, architecture, game-development, mobile-development

im making a game on react native and to have multiple players i used socket io to have real time data communication. The problem im facing is that 4 devices in 1 room playing having lag problems because of too much socket events going to the server and to the device.

Im trying to solve this problem using RabbitMQ but i have no idea if this is the right way.

RabbitMQ server between the socket server and devices. This is the architecture i have in mind , what do yall think?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a great idea! Any idea what the amount of messages you are sending per second is and what is average size per message?

Comment: i believe the data would be just a single object with a few fields. no nested objects cuz im trying to keep it light as possible plus since its a card game i believe the message being sent would be around 5 per room an action hence for a round it would be around 30-40

Comment: You will need to setup some queues. But 30-40 message per second each device should be able to handle those message with a socket connection and without rabbitmq unless there is a lot of computation that is happening on each message.